# Spring Rest Set Custom Object in Context

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, security

I am using Spring Rest for creating Rest APIs. For authentication, I have created a filter that extends from `OncePerRequestFilter`, this filter check if a valid token is present in the header. I have to set some custom object information in Spring context. So that I can retrieve it in my Controller classes. Something like:

```
AuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    // validation goes here

    requestContext.setSecurityContext(new SecurityContext() {
        public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
            return new UserInfo("", token, userID, userType);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: so what is question ?

Comment: requestContext.setSecurityContext does not work with Spring Rest. I am looking for equivalent in spring

Comment: actually you can do something like this  SecurityContext sc = SecurityContextHolder.getContext(); and then securityContext.setAuthentication(auth); // set authentication object as customized authentication object check this website https://www.baeldung.com/manually-set-user-authentication-spring-security

Answer (score 0):

Don't create custom filters for authentications. User security context instead it's pretty powerful.

I don't know about any option how put custom object into spring context. But I can show you how to create your custom context in spring framework and then use it as any other context. Of course you will be able to put custom objects into it.

PSEUDO CODE:

1.)
Create custom object which you want to have in context:

```
public class UserInfo implements Serializable {

private String id;    
private String email;

//Getters and setters
}
```

2.)
Create custom context:

```
@Service
public class UserInfoContext {

private static final ThreadLocal<UserInfo> userInfoThreadLocal = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();

public void setUserInfo(UserInfo userInfo) {
    UserInfoContext.userInfoThreadLocal.set(userInfo);
}

public UserInfo getUserInfo() {
    return UserInfoContext.userInfoThreadLocal.get();
}

public void clearContext() {
    UserInfoContext.userInfoThreadLocal.remove();
}
}
```

3.)
Create custom interceptor for initializing custom object inside custom context

```
@Service
public class UserInfoInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

private UserInfoContext userInfoContext;

@Autowired
public UserInfoInterceptor(UserInfoContext userInfoContext) {
    this.userInfoContext = userInfoContext;
}

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest requestServlet, HttpServletResponse responseServlet, Object handler) throws Exception {
    // Call userInfoContext.setUserInfo() with custom data.
    return true;
}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception exception) throws Exception {
    userInfoContext.clearContext();
}
}
```

Thanks to ThreadLocal you are able to save custom information about current user.